# balls and boxes optimization

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

There are $n$ balls, among which $m$ balls are bad, and hence $n-m$ are good. We are given a number of boxes. We want to put balls into boxes such that all the good balls (or most of them, e.g., $99$%) are in good boxes. A box is called **good** if containing only good balls. The thing is that we cannot distinguish a good ball with a bad one. We can only know whether a box is good or not once putting balls into it. A trivial solution is to put only one ball into each box. However, this requires $n$ boxes. My objective is to minimize the number of boxes required to achieve that with high probability, all or most of the good balls are in good boxes. Is this a known problem? What is the structure of an optimal strategy?

Comment: your description of bad box is unclear. a bad box is one with (at least) one bad ball? so a box is neither good nor bad until a ball is put into it? is that how to understand the "we cannot know...until" part?

Comment: [*group testing*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing)

Comment: @kodiu yes, a box is bad as long as one bad ball is put in it; we can tell a box is good or bad after putting balls.